# UriBuilder and "../../" in uri

Tags: c#, uri

I need to combine two urls, but it seems that UriBuilder doesn't support url's with ../../ in them. Is my only option to code this by hand? I'm trying something like this :

```
Uri pageUri = new Uri("http://site.com/a/b/c.html");
string redirectUrl = "../../x.html";

UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(pageUri);
builder.Path += redirectUrl;
```

Thanks for any tips on how to do this the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also to use:

```
Uri redirect = new Uri(
    new Uri("http://site.com/a/b/c.html"), "../../x.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. You tried to call `builder.Uri.OriginalString` to get the full address back?